# WPF ListView Binding showing class namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a ListView in my XAML defined as

```
<vm:JobListView x:Name="JobEditor" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=JobListViewSource}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Width="10" HeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource FirstColumnGridViewColumnHeader}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyColumnTemplate}" />
            <vm:SortListViewColumn Header="Description" Width="100" SortProperty="Description" SortStyle="JobDataGridViewColumnHeader" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DescriptionColumnTemplate}" />

            <vm:SortListViewColumn Header="Staff" Width="100" SortProperty="Staff.FirstName" SortStyle="JobDataGridViewColumnHeader" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StaffColumnTemplate}" />

            <vm:SortListViewColumn Header="Client" Width="50" SortProperty="Client.Name"  SortStyle="JobDataGridViewColumnHeader" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ClientColumnTemplate}" />

            <vm:SortListViewColumn Header="Samples" Width="100" SortProperty="Samples" SortStyle="JobDataGridViewColumnHeader" CellTemplate="{StaticResource SamplesNoColumnTemplate}" />

            <vm:SortListViewColumn Header="Entry Date" Width="100" SortProperty="EntryDate" SortStyle="JobDataGridViewColumnHeader" CellTemplate="{StaticResource EntryDateColumnTemplate}" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="10" CellTemplate="{StaticResource EmptyColumnTemplate}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</vm:JobListView>
```

vm:JobListView is a class that inherits from ListView

The CellTemplates are defined like this:-

```
<!-- description column -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="DescriptionColumnTemplate">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The ItemsSource is bound to a property on my VM defined like this:-

```
public ICollectionView JobListViewSource
{
    get { return Get(() => JobListViewSource); }
    set { Set(() => JobListViewSource, value); }
}
```

and I set the property like this:-

```
CollectionViewSource source = new CollectionViewSource();
source.Source = this.Jobs;
this.JobListViewSource = source.View;
```

where Jobs is an ObservableCollection of Job objects

What I get displayed in my grid is just the namespace of the Job object and not the individual properties in each column

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

this.JobListViewSource.SourceCollection=this.Jobs instead of

```
CollectionViewSource source = new CollectionViewSource();
source.Source = this.Jobs;
this.JobListViewSource = source.View;
```

Comment: Alternatively define JobListViewSource of type CollectionViewSource and use it's Source property   this.JobListViewSource.Source=this.Jobs;